# Does ActiveMQ QueueBrowser load entire contents of queue into memory?

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

When we use the [`javax.jms.QueueBrowser.getEnumeration()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/QueueBrowser.html#getEnumeration--) will it only browse the queue content inside the JVM? Will it significantly affect application memory usage?

Also, when we use queue browser to get the queue itself, then so much data actually takes up memory which will not be the case with `getEnumeration()`. Please help me understand if I am right.

Comment: What do you mean by "the queue content inside the JVM"?

Comment: When you refer to "application memory usage" are you talking about the application executing the QueueBrowser or the ActiveMQ broker itself?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "when we use queue browser to get the queue itself"?

Comment: Yes, I meant application executing the queue browser

Comment: From docs :: A client uses a QueueBrowser object to look at messages on a queue without removing them.
The getEnumeration method returns a java.util.Enumeration that is used to scan the queue's messages. It may be an enumeration of the entire content of a queue, or it may contain only the messages matching a message selector.                    Does this mean that queue contents are not loaded into appliacation memory when we do getEnumeration?

Answer (score 0):

A certain amount of messages are prefetched when you consume a queue with a `QueueBrowser`. This limit can be configured in [ActiveMQPrefetchPolicy on an ActiveMQConnectionFactory](http://activemq.apache.org/what-is-the-prefetch-limit-for.html). The property `queueBrowserPrefetch` regulates number of messages received in a batch, and buffered into memory until all are acknowledged.

Comment: Hi Anton, could you please tell me how do I acknowledge it If I use browser prefetch ?  Is it just l the normal way - like if we used client acknowledge to produce into a queue, now if I am accessing messages using browser with prefetch 10, then after every message in the enumeration, I just need to do message.acknowlede ? There are no sample examples for this.. thanks for the help !

Comment: From docs :: A client uses a QueueBrowser object to look at messages on a queue without removing them. The getEnumeration method returns a java.util.Enumeration that is used to scan the queue's messages. It may be an enumeration of the entire content of a queue, or it may contain only the messages matching a message selector. Does this mean that queue contents are not loaded into appliacation memory when we do getEnumeration?

Comment: An acknowledge mode is set on JMS session in the `createSession` method. There're [3 acknowledge modes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/bncfw/index.html). When using `AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE`, which is pretty much a default option for most cases, you don't need to acknowledge messages manually in your code.

Comment: Messages are initially dispatched when `QueueBrowser` is created. You may set low prefetch value (1 to 10) if memory consumption is your concern.

Comment: Thanks Anton, Can this information please be added on ActiveMQ documentation related to Queue Browser?

Comment: I'm not an ActiveMQ contributor, you may report them an issue if you find an important aspect missing in documentation